# How to scroll multiple pages with page snapping with Flutter PageView?

Tags: flutter-animation

I am using PageView.builder to display around 50 images which cover the whole viewport (viewportFraction: 1.0). The user should be able to scroll the images slowly by swiping slowly and fast by swiping fast. When the desired image is seen, the user should be able to "hold" the image which should then snap to the viewport. I have seen this type of behaviour in other apps but cannot figure out how to do it with Flutter.

pageSnapping:true fixes the desired snapping, but then one cannot scroll past several images with one swipe.

```
child: PageView.builder(
      pageSnapping: false,
      onPageChanged: (index) {print(index);} ,
      controller: pageController,
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      itemCount: dogList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
           image = dogList[index];
           return SizedBox.expand(child: Image.file(image, fit:BoxFit.cover)                        
      }),
```

When the scrolling is stopped by holding down the finger on the desired image, it typically stays with parts of two adjacent images shown.

Update: I found a solution. If I wrap the PageView.builder with a NotificationListener, I can detect the ScrollEndNotification and get the location from pageController.page.toInt(), save it and do a setState. Then in the build I can do pageController.animateToPage to the saved location.

This works reasonably well, the user experience takes some getting used to.

This should be an option on PageController or PageView, not requiring any coding.

Answer (score 4):

### Usage of plugins

What you are looking for is is a carousel behavior, there are already a few plugins available such as [carousel_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) or some native flutter documentation to a [photo-filter-carousel](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/effects/photo-filter-carousel) which also has the same behavior.

### Based on your approach **(Best option)**

You already had a great idea with changing `pageSnapping` to false to disable the internal physics of PageView. Now we can easily extend (and overwrite the snap physics and also configure `velocityPerOverscroll` (logical pixels per second) for our needs.

```dart
PageView(
   pageSnapping: false,
   physics: const PageOverscrollPhysics(velocityPerOverscroll: 1000),
```

**Overwritten Snap-Phyics**

```dart
class PageOverscrollPhysics extends ScrollPhysics {
  ///The logical pixels per second until a page is overscrolled.
  ///A satisfying value can be determined by experimentation.
  ///
  ///Example:
  ///If the user scroll velocity is 3500 pixel/second and [velocityPerOverscroll]=
  ///1000, then 3.5 pages will be overscrolled/skipped.
  final double velocityPerOverscroll;

  const PageOverscrollPhysics({
    ScrollPhysics? parent,
    this.velocityPerOverscroll = 1000,
  }) : super(parent: parent);

  @override
  PageOverscrollPhysics applyTo(ScrollPhysics? ancestor) {
    return PageOverscrollPhysics(
      parent: buildParent(ancestor)!,
    );
  }

  double _getTargetPixels(ScrollMetrics position, double velocity) {
    double page = position.pixels / position.viewportDimension;
    page += velocity / velocityPerOverscroll;
    double pixels = page.roundToDouble() * position.viewportDimension;
    return pixels;
  }

  @override
  Simulation? createBallisticSimulation(
      ScrollMetrics position, double velocity) {
    // If we're out of range and not headed back in range, defer to the parent
    // ballistics, which should put us back in range at a page boundary.
    if ((velocity <= 0.0 && position.pixels <= position.minScrollExtent) ||
        (velocity >= 0.0 && position.pixels >= position.maxScrollExtent)) {
      return super.createBallisticSimulation(position, velocity);
    }
    final double target = _getTargetPixels(position, velocity);
    if (target != position.pixels) {
      return ScrollSpringSimulation(spring, position.pixels, target, velocity,
          tolerance: tolerance);
    }
    return null;
  }

  @override
  bool get allowImplicitScrolling => false;
}
```

Although PageOverscrollPhysics might look crazy complicated, it's essentially just an adjustment of the `PageScrollPhysics()`class.

Comment: I think `velocityPerOverscroll` is missing in the `applyTo` function. Besides this, it works like a charm :)

Comment: Feel free to edit the answer. I am not sure what you mean (has been a while).